# failed to install 'graphviz*' packages with yum command on my RHEL server

Tags: linux, graphviz, yum

I failed to install 'graphviz' on my RHEL server using 'yum' command

I downloaded graphviz-rhel.repo,and saved it at /etc/yum.repos.d/ following www.graphviz.org.Then I use "yum -y install 'graphviz*' ". But there are some errors.
Can someone help me?How to install this?
The error messages:

--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: graphviz-lang-ocaml-2.38.0-1.el6.x86_64 (graphviz-stable)
           Requires: ocaml(List) = a0e2e49d266ff302f8667651a43f71ba

Error: Package: graphviz-lang-ruby-2.38.0-1.el6.x86_64 (graphviz-stable)
           Requires: /usr/bin/ruby

Error: Package: graphviz-lang-guile-2.38.0-1.el6.x86_64 (graphviz-stable)
           Requires: libguile.so.17()(64bit)

Error: Package: graphviz-lang-ocaml-2.38.0-1.el6.x86_64 (graphviz-stable)
           Requires: ocaml(Int32) = b2545c419b6b6a173cac4c0a3e7e0277

Error: Package: graphviz-lang-ocaml-2.38.0-1.el6.x86_64 (graphviz-stable)
           Requires: ocaml

Error: Package: graphviz-x-2.38.0-1.el6.x86_64 (graphviz-stable)
           Requires: libglut.so.3()(64bit)

Error: Package: graphviz-2.38.0-1.el6.x86_64 (graphviz-stable)
           Requires: libANN.so.1()(64bit)

Error: Package: graphviz-lang-java-2.38.0-1.el6.x86_64 (graphviz-stable)
           Requires: java

Error: Package: graphviz-lang-ocaml-2.38.0-1.el6.x86_64 (graphviz-stable)
           Requires: ocaml(Callback) = 71e1f9b7f211661f1dfeedab5ffae0cc

Error: Package: graphviz-lang-guile-2.38.0-1.el6.x86_64 (graphviz-stable)
           Requires: guile

Error: Package: graphviz-plugins-x-2.38.0-1.el6.x86_64 (graphviz-stable)
           Requires: librsvg-2.so.2()(64bit)

Error: Package: graphviz-lang-ruby-2.38.0-1.el6.x86_64 (graphviz-stable)
           Requires: libruby.so.1.8()(64bit)

Error: Package: graphviz-lang-ocaml-2.38.0-1.el6.x86_64 (graphviz-stable)
           Requires: ocaml(Int64) = d501d6e89fdce41c79f274fb464995d5

Error: Package: graphviz-lang-php-2.38.0-1.el6.x86_64 (graphviz-stable)
           Requires: /usr/bin/php

Error: Package: graphviz-lang-ocaml-2.38.0-1.el6.x86_64 (graphviz-stable)
           Requires: ocaml(Obj) = 57b3fe2fcfe45ee25709b8ae556264d1

Error: Package: graphviz-lang-ocaml-2.38.0-1.el6.x86_64 (graphviz-stable)
           Requires: ocaml(Pervasives) = 88cb1505c8bdf9a4dcd2cdf3452732b4

Error: Package: graphviz-lang-ruby-2.38.0-1.el6.x86_64 (graphviz-stable)
           Requires: ruby

Error: Package: graphviz-lang-ocaml-2.38.0-1.el6.x86_64 (graphviz-stable)
           Requires: ocaml(Hashtbl) = ee2a3220e38a4350c5bc131ce9f3f6ce

Error: Package: graphviz-gd-2.38.0-1.el6.x86_64 (graphviz-stable)
           Requires: libgd.so.2()(64bit)

Error: Package: graphviz-x-2.38.0-1.el6.x86_64 (graphviz-stable)
           Requires: libgtkglext-x11-1.0.so.0()(64bit)

Error: Package: graphviz-lang-tcl-2.38.0-1.el6.x86_64 (graphviz-stable)
           Requires: libgd.so.2()(64bit)

Error: Package: graphviz-plugins-x-2.38.0-1.el6.x86_64 (graphviz-stable)
           Requires: libpoppler-glib.so.4()(64bit)

Error: Package: graphviz-lang-ocaml-2.38.0-1.el6.x86_64 (graphviz-stable)
           Requires: ocaml(Array) = 9c9fa5f11e2d6992c427dde4d1168489

Error: Package: graphviz-x-2.38.0-1.el6.x86_64 (graphviz-stable)
           Requires: libgdkglext-x11-1.0.so.0()(64bit)

Error: Package: graphviz-lang-ocaml-2.38.0-1.el6.x86_64 (graphviz-stable)
           Requires: ocaml(runtime) = 3.11.2

Error: Package: gts-0.7.6-14.el6.x86_64 (graphviz-stable)
           Requires: libnetpbm.so.10()(64bit)

Error: Package: graphviz-lang-ocaml-2.38.0-1.el6.x86_64 (graphviz-stable)
           Requires: ocaml(Gc) = bf884f8416bc19d4f57421e499a1aa8a

Error: Package: graphviz-plugins-gd-2.38.0-1.el6.x86_64 (graphviz-stable)
           Requires: libgd.so.2()(64bit)

You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

I know the problem is about packages dependency,but yum can resolve dependency auto,isn't it?
How to install it with no wrong?

Really thanks,
Bruce

Answer (score 0):

I found why this happen yesterday.
The problem is that 'graphviz*' depend on these packages.But this packages can not been found in current repo source.

Answer (score 0):

1. download from [ann-libs-1.1.1-4.el6.x86_64.rpm](http://ftp.linux.ncsu.edu/mirror/ftp.redhat.com/pub/epel/6/x86_64/ann-libs-1.1.1-4.el6.x86_64.rpm)
2. rpm -ivh ann-libs-1.1.1-4.el6.x86_64.rpm
3. yum install 'graphviz*'