# Yum install graphviz on RHEL 7 fails with 'No package graphviz available.'

Tags: yum, rhel7

I am trying to install graphviz on my RHEL VM. when I run

```
$sudo yum install graphviz
```

I get this:

```
This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.
No package graphviz available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I later found out that I get this same problem with all packages.

I have tried several solutions I have found online such as:

1. saving the .repo file found [here](https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/uploads/84f531a0571a194f82f015b9d672c61f/graphviz-rhel.repo) (this link will download the file)

then running

```
#from dir containing graphviz-rhel.repo
$sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo graphviz-rhel.repo
```

the output was

```
This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.
adding repo from: graphviz-rhel.repo
grabbing file graphviz-rhel.repo to /etc/yum.repos.d/graphviz-rhel.repo
repo saved to /etc/yum.repos.d/graphviz-rhel.repo
```

Then I ran

```
$sudo yum-config-manager --enable graphviz-rhel
```

This gives no output and `$yum-config-manager list all` does not list anything related to graphviz as a repo (enabled or disabled)

2. I tried the solution here: [failed to install 'graphviz*' packages with yum command on my RHEL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763282/failed-to-install-graphviz-packages-with-yum-command-on-my-rhel-server)

except I found the rpm file [here](http://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/fedora/devel/rawhide/aarch64/g/graphviz-2.40.1-44.fc30.aarch64.html)

When I ran the rpm command I got an error because I was missing a couple dozen dependencies so I dont think following this solution for all of them is a reasonable solution.

If someone can either inform me why one of these didn't work or let me know how to accomplish my goal of getting `yum install <package>` to work I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Do you have a RHEL subscription? If so, activate it. If not, use CentOS instead.

Comment: @JosephSible unfortunately we have one but I was told accessing it may be a difficult process. Is that a requirement in order to do what I am asking. if so I will mark this as closed

Comment: Yes, it's a requirement. You can't yum install/update/anything in the official repositories on a RHEL system without an active subscription. Even if you have a third-party repository with the package you want, it will almost certainly have dependencies that it expects to be available in the system repositories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As posted in the comments, in order to utilize yum on a RHEL system you need an active subscription